# Custom legend in Highcharts Variwide

Tags: highcharts, legend, x-axis

Based on an existing sample, I have added a custom legend on a Highcharts Variwide chart.
The legend works very well! Result is visible here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/d4mrnu2h/

The only next feature I need is to hide/show the corresponding label on the X axis when I click on a legend item. This have to work also when horizontally scrolling on the chart.

I tried to use the function

```
this.series.xAxis.ticks[x].label.hide();
```

in the legendItemClick function but id doesn't works very well (especially when I scroll).

How to achieve that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xAxis.labels.formatter()` function for conditional display of the name if the point is visible:

```js
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return this.axis.series[0].points[this.pos].visible ? this.value : '';
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfcq9xz8/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Thanks for that but it really works only for "displayed" items. For instance, on your Demo, if you click on the item "Italy" in the legend (Italy is not displayed on the default view because the scrollbar is on the left), then you scroll to the right, you'll see the label Italy (between Ireland and United Kingdom).

Comment: You're right, I corrected the answer. A better solution is to use `xAxis.labels.formatter()`